# Display mySql table in a label in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stringbuilder, dataview

I'm trying to implement an application combine with mysql database. I want to show **table1** like in a terminal view instead of displaying it in a datagrid view. I'm using the code below to connect and display from MySql Database:

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1";
MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        myConn.Close();
```

This code only execute the last value of the table. but, I want to display whole table plus I want it to show in a label. So that I can style it like a terminal view.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: I am not sure it is good idea. Have you tried like this `label1.Text +=` for concatenation of strings.

Comment: your code is receiving all data, but it is getting replaced with next data.
so you can see only last value.

Comment: I would suggest using a `StringBuilder` and it's `AppendFormat` method to build the output, then call its `ToString` method at the end and set the `Text` of the `Label` once only.  If you use a fixed-width font then you can display the data in "columns" by using appropriate formatting: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?545102-Formatting-Fixed-width-Text-Output&highlight=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `MySqlDataReader.FieldCount Property` will be useful.

Try this code:

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1";
MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            if(label1.Text.Length > 0)
                 label1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

            for(int i=0; i<myReader.FieldCount; i++)
                label1.Text += myReader[i].ToString() + "    ";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    myConn.Close();
```

**NOTE**: It is recommeded to use `using` statement for `mysqlconnection`, `mysqldatareader` and `mysqlcommand`.

**UPDATE** (using `StringBuilder` as recommended by jmcilhinney):

```
// Method used to retrieve data from DB
string GetFormattedText()
{
    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";            

    using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
    {
        myConn.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1";

            using (MySqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               try
               {
                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                   while (myReader.Read())
                   {
                       if (sb.Length > 0)
                           sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                        for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
                           sb.AppendFormat("{0}    ", myReader[i]);                               
                    }

                    return sb.ToString();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
            }
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
 label1.Text = GetFormattedText();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. There's another thing I want to add. How can I sync database table. I can't use a timer because It will show all the data again and again instead of getting only updated data. is there any solution for that?

Comment: You are welcome. For sync you have to call this method again, but before loading data in the `label1` you have to make it empty. Just add a line `label1.Text = string.Empty;` before `while-loop`.

Comment: It's not good practice to keep modifying controls over and over like that, or to keep creating and throwing away `String` objects.  Better to construct a `StringBuilder` as you read the data, then create one `String` and update the control once at the end.

Comment: @HassanNisar I don't think It'll be a good idea. Because, when the database gets larger, the application will get more response time to get bunch of data.

Comment: jmcilhinney said it right. Using `StringBuilder` is quite appropriate. But @UserPhalcon, I don't think it will be efficient to update portion of label1.Text depending upon the values changed in db.